# Probability: normal distribution and standard normal random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, solution-verification

> Let $X$ follows the normal distribution $N(1,9)$. Find
>
> $\text{(a)}$ $P(X\le1.4).$
>
> $\text{(b)}$ $P(X\le-1.22).$
>
> $\text{(c)}$ Hence find $P(-1.22\le X\le1.4).$

For $\text{(a)}$, is the answer $0.5530$?

For $\text{(b)}$, is the answer $0.2296$?

For $\text{(c)}$, is the answer $0.3234$?

> Find $k$ such that $$P(-k\le Z\le k)=0.97$$ where $Z$ is the standard
>   normal random variable.

For this question, is $k=2.17$?

Comment: It all looks correct to me. Good job!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, indeed, your calculations are all correct! Well done.

---

NOTE: However, that being said, the most important thing here is *how* you arrived at the correct answers. Usually, we can infer from a correct answer that the method used to arrive at it is correct. But not always.

So if you have any questions or doubts about *how* you arrived at your answers, feel free to elaborate, and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Needs a TU - +1